# how to print 2 nested grids to console in C++?

Tags: c++, printing, datagrid, grid, ascii

I'm trying to print a grid inside each of the cells of another grid.
to be specific. imagine a 7x7 grid which each cell is 3x3. also i need padding between each cells of parent grid. for the second grid which is 3v3 , each cell prints a number between 1-9 which is given in the function of child grid.

for example

```
function childGridprinter(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
//the result of child grind should be like this:
  a
b   c
  d
return "\n..a";
}
```

this will be embedder into parent grid like for 3v3 inside 3v3 :

```
  a       a      a
b   c   b   c  b    c
  d       d       d

  a       a      a
b   c   b   c  b    c
  d       d       d

  a       a      a
b   c   b   c  b    c
  d       d       d
```

if its not possible using console, whats the easy solution.
thanks in advance.

I already have a printing function which prints a grid with values but expanding it to show more data was needed. for example each cell needs to show north,east,west and south data(between 1-9).
i don't wanna go for opengl because its hard to implement it in my code.

Comment: Create a single big matrix (21x21) and feed it from your matrix of cells?

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain words. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to their rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes but i need it to be dynamically created. that i feed first matrix dimensions then second. then it create it .

Comment: @SamVarshavchik man i tried step by step pen and paper. i could hard code the ascii structure without loops but i need it in a way that i could feed the inner matix/grid with my numbers as parent grid iterates.

Comment: You can calculate the width and height of the final grid. Then use std::vector<std::vector<char>> to allocate the final output grid. Loop over y and x (using the width/height of the output grid) and calculate the index into your "stamp" (the a-b-c-d pattern) using a modulo operator (if that result falls outside the stamp print a space).

Comment: Is  this a school excercise?

Comment: @PepijnKramer no its not. i'm trying just to print my data into console rather than taking it into matlab.

Comment: I have this example for you then : https://onlinegdb.com/QtuDj_K5H

Comment: @PepijnKramer YES IT WORKS!!!. i cannot mark comments as answer. set it as answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, I did not post it as an answer before because this (usually) isn't a coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

auto make_grid(const std::size_t horizontal_repeat, const std::size_t vertical_repeat, const std::vector<std::vector<char>>& stamp)
{
#if _DEBUG
    assert(horizontal_repeat >= 1);
    assert(vertical_repeat >= 1);
    assert(stamp.size() >= 1);
    assert(stamp[0].size() >= 1);

    for (const auto& row : stamp)
    {
        assert(stamp[0].size() == row.size());
    }
#endif

    // The total width and height of the output
    // (width-1) spaces and (heigh-1) empty lines will be added.
    std::size_t total_width = (horizontal_repeat * stamp.size()) + (horizontal_repeat - 1ul);
    std::size_t total_height = (vertical_repeat * stamp.size()) + (vertical_repeat - 1ul);

    // the output array
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> grid(total_height, std::vector<char>(total_width));

    // allow for 1 extra space or extra empty line
    std::size_t stamp_height = { stamp.size() + 1ul };
    std::size_t stamp_width = { stamp[0].size() + 1ul };

    for (std::size_t y{ 0ul }; y < total_height; ++y)
    {
        // calculate the vertical offset in the stamp
        // but also allow for an space
        std::size_t stamp_y = y % stamp_height;

        for (std::size_t x{ 0ul }; x < total_width; ++x)
        {
            std::size_t stamp_x = x % stamp_width;

            // if the horizontal or vertical offset are outside the size of the input stamp
            // output a space otherwise use the values from the stamp
            auto output_char = ((stamp_y == stamp.size()) || (stamp_x == stamp[0].size())) ? ' ' : stamp[stamp_y][stamp_x];
            grid[y][x] = output_char;
        }
    }

    return grid;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::vector<char>>& grid)
{
    for (const auto& row : grid)
    {
        for (const auto c : row)
        {
            std::cout << c;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return os;
}

// and then the program is just those two lines.
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> stamp{ {'.','e','.'}, {'f','*','g'}, {'.','h','.'} };
    std::cout << make_grid(4, 3, stamp);

    return 0;
}
```